# Spring Cloud AWS SQS SendTo annotation with property placeholder

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-aws

[This issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/65) suggests that the @SendTo annotation supports property placeholders, but I can't get it to work. Here's some simplified code snippets of what I'm trying to do (easier than trying to explain with words). I'm on spring-cloud-aws version 1.2.1.

This works:

```
@Component
public class InputQueueListener {

    @Value("${replyQueueProperty}")
    private String replyQueue;

    @Autowired
    private QueueMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

    @SqsListener(value = "${inputQueueProperty}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NEVER)
    private void receiveMessage(final Message message, final Acknowledgment acknowledgment, @Header("ApproximateReceiveCount") final int receiveCount) throws Exception {
        final Reply reply = doStuff(message);

        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(replyQueue, reply);
    }
}
```

And this works:

```
@Component
public class InputQueueListener {

    @SqsListener(value = "${inputQueueProperty}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NEVER)
    @SendTo("replyQueueActualName")
    private Reply receiveMessage(final Message message, final Acknowledgment acknowledgment, @Header("ApproximateReceiveCount") final int receiveCount) throws Exception {
        final Reply reply = doStuff(message);

        return reply;
    }
}
```

But this does not work:

```
@Component
public class InputQueueListener {

    @SqsListener(value = "${inputQueueProperty}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NEVER)
    @SendTo("${replyQueueProperty}")
    private Reply receiveMessage(final Message message, final Acknowledgment acknowledgment, @Header("ApproximateReceiveCount") final int receiveCount) throws Exception {
        final Reply reply = doStuff(message);

        return reply;
    }
}
```

This fails with a NonExistentQueue exception. But the queue exists, and the first two methods send messages to it just fine.
What am I missing?! I have checked for typos a million times, I'm pretty sure that's not it :)

Just in case, this is my configuration:

```
@Bean
public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate(final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs, final ResourceIdResolver resourceIdResolver) {
    final QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate = new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSqs, resourceIdResolver);
    return queueMessagingTemplate;
}

@Lazy
@Bean(name = "amazonSQS", destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSClient() {

    final AmazonSQSAsync awsSQSAsyncClient;

    awsSQSAsyncClient = AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withRegion(Regions.fromName(System.getProperty("cloud.aws.region.static")))
            .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
            .build();
    return awsSQSAsyncClient;
}

@Bean
public QueueMessageHandler queueMessageHandler(final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
    final QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMsgHandlerFactory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
    queueMsgHandlerFactory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSqs);

    final QueueMessageHandler queueMessageHandler = queueMsgHandlerFactory.createQueueMessageHandler();

    return queueMessageHandler;
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
    final SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory msgListenerContainerFactory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
    msgListenerContainerFactory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSqs);
    msgListenerContainerFactory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(5);
    msgListenerContainerFactory.setWaitTimeOut(20);

    return msgListenerContainerFactory;
}


@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer(final QueueMessageHandler messageHandler, final SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory) {
    final SimpleMessageListenerContainer msgListenerContainer = simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory.createSimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    msgListenerContainer.setMessageHandler(messageHandler);

    return msgListenerContainer;
}

@Bean
public DynamicQueueUrlDestinationResolver destinationResolver(final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs, final ResourceIdResolver resourceIdResolver) {
    DynamicQueueUrlDestinationResolver destinationResolver = new DynamicQueueUrlDestinationResolver(amazonSqs, resourceIdResolver);
    return destinationResolver;
}

@Bean
public QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMessageHandlerFactory(final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
    QueueMessageHandlerFactory factory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
    factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSqs);

    return factory;
}
```

Comment: You might want to see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51621607/499635