# Use Property Placeholder with Spring AMQP @SendTo Annotation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp

I have the same problem mentioned in this unanswered question: [Spring Cloud AWS SQS SendTo annotation with property placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071361/spring-cloud-aws-sqs-sendto-annotation-with-property-placeholder)

But, I'm asking it again more succinctly in hopes that it will be answered this time.

As mentioned in the question I had referred to, this issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/65 seems to indicated that the `@SentTo` annotation should support property placeholders.

However, when it comes to the `@SendTo` annotation, the Spring AMQP documentation only talks about SpEL (bean evaluation '#{...}' and runtime '!{...}'), but doesn't mention property placeholders.

When I tried using `@SendTo("${my.reply.routing.key}")` or `@SendTo("${my-exchange}/${my.reply.routing.key}")`, is being interpreted literally and isn't being properly interpolated.

Are there any workarounds for me to use property placeholder in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only supports expressions; you can work around it, though; such as by using a bean reference:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So51620793Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So51620793Application.class, args);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
    @SendTo("#{@sendTo}")
    public String listen(Message in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        return new String(in.getBody()).toUpperCase();
    }

    @Bean
    public String sendTo(@Value("${foo.bar}") String sendTo) {
        return sendTo;
    }

}
```

I am not familiar with the AWS code; each project rolls its own for this annotation.

Comment: AWS wasn't a concern for me. It was only for the poster of the original question. Although it would have been great to use property placeholders like I can with the `@RabbitListner` and `@Queue` annotations, your workaround will work for me. Thanks!

Comment: I have found that this can be used as well `@SendTo("#{environment['foo.bar']}"`

Comment: See the fix here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/pull/785